# A matrix with imaginary entries satisfies the property?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

> Let $A$ be $n\times n$ complex matrix. If $A$ is both Hermitian and Unitary, then show that absolute value of all eigenvalues are $1$.

I just know what is Hermitian and Unitary matrix, and that's all. I can't go further.

$$A^{\mathrm{H}}A = AA^{\mathrm{H}}=I_{n}$$ is unitary
and,

$$A^{\mathrm{H}}=A$$ means A is Hermitian.

Comment: The problem statement doesn't seem to say anything about imaginary entries, but the title does. Do you mean complex entries?

Comment: Yes, I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the magnitude of eigenvalues of a unitary matrix by thinking about the eigenvectors.
Let $v, \lambda$ be any eigenvector, eigenvalue pair of $A$, so we have $Av=v\lambda$. We can write $A^HAv = I v$ by the nature of $A$ being unitary, as the matrices cancel each other out.

By using the hermetian symmetry  we can write $A^H Av = AAv = Av\lambda = v \lambda^2$.

This gives the property of $\lambda^2 = 1$ which has only two possible solutions.

In fact, it is somewhat enough talking about unitary properties to conclude your $|\lambda| = 1$ claim. The hermitian symmetry reduces the possible values to numbers on the real line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand!

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax = \lambda x$ then
$$x=Ix =A^HAx = A^H(\lambda x) = A(\lambda x) = \lambda^2 x$$
so clearly $\lambda^2 = 1$. This implies $|\lambda| = 1$.

Comment: By the way, all eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real. So absolute value if $1$ is equivalent to $\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda = -1$ as I have shown above.

Comment: Thank you for this. It helped!